# Regular expression for custom Time string

Tags: java, android, regex, time

I made an android program allowing the user to enter a custom "time" string, for example:

- "**3h**" (meaning 3 hours)
- "**2m30s**" (meaning 2 minutes and 30 seconds)
- "**2h962s**" (meaning 2 hours and 962 seconds (sic))
- "**1h5s6c**" (meaning 1 hour, 5 seconds and 6 hundredths of a second)
- "**5h78m228c**" (meaning 5 hours, 78 minutes (sic) and 228 hundredths of a second (sic))

I've been using this regular expression to validate that custom time string:
**^([0-9]?[0-9]h)?([0-9]+m)?([0-9]+s)?([0-9]+c)?$**
(therefore allowing a max of 99 hours, and unlimited number of minutes, seconds and hundredths of a second)

The problem is that I'd like to make **optional** the **last** unit, in order to make the program **silently** using the **following** unit. In the above examples, the user would be allowed to enter these strings instead of the above:

- "***3***" (not specifying "h", in order to make the program treat "3" as "3 hours")
- "***2m30***" (not specifying "s", in order to make the program treat "30" as "30 seconds")
- "**2h962s**" (same, because without specifying "s" the program would treat "962" as "962 minutes")
- "***1h5s6***" (not specifying "c", in order to make the program treat "6" as "6 hundredths of a second")
- "**5h78m228c**" (same, because without specifying "c" the program would treat "228" as "228 seconds")

Which regular expression would I have then to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
^([0-9]?[0-9](h|$))?([0-9]+(m|$))?([0-9]+(s|$))?([0-9]+(c|$))?$
```

Every time you check for a time unit, alternatively allow the end of a string.